# How to properly indicate the reference year of NPV that is in the past?

Tags: microeconomics, discount-rate

Say we are in the year 2023. I have computed the NPV with Year 0 set in 2019.
(Reason: for comparison of actual vs initial projection in 2019 basis period).

What is the acceptable norm to quote the NPV to make it explicit that it is discounted way in the past instead of this year?

- NPV@WACC = 100 (2019)
- NPV@WACC = 100 (Ref 2019)
- NPV@WACC = 100 (Discounted to 2019)
- or something else that's *even more proper?